# Get the specific value from the last part of a String in Android

Tags: java, android, string

I wanted to get the value from the last part of a String, here's my example String

> String str="www.mywebsite.com?id=0001&user=myname"

I like to get the word **myname** from that String, All examples that I'm seeing is like this

```
String getUser = str.substring(str.length() - 6);
```

but user value length changes every transaction so I can't fix that to any value. Can anyone please help me in how I will be able to get the user value from that String. Thanks.

Comment: Use `String.lastIndexOf()` instead of `str.length() - 6`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String getUser=str.subString(str.lastIndexOf("=")+1,Str.length());
```

Will return myname.

Comment: Thank you ,this works perfectly! but there are some letter that you type in uppercase instead of a lower case so I will edit you answer. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

If your string is going to be a uri, you can use Uri's getQueryParameter:

```
String str="www.mywebsite.com?id=0001&user=myname";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(str);
return uri.getQueryParameter("user");
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String getUser = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("=") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String foo = "www.mywebsite.com?id=0001&user=myname";
String[] split = foo.split("=");
String name = split[split.length-1];
```

with String.split(), you can split strings with a delimiter and put the values in an array. It is similar to PHPs' explode method.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="www.mywebsite.com?id=0001&user=myname";
String user = getQueryParamValue(str);

public static final String getQueryParam(String url) {
    List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url), "UTF-8");

    for (NameValuePair param : params){
        if("user".equalsIgnoreCase(param.getName())) {
            return param.getValue();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: NameValuePair is deprecated better to use Uri